# how we get server data without using any background thread and return function value after get server data

Tags: android, http

I need sever time at every button click for validation to solve the problem of change mobile time manually. I need one function that gets a date from the server and returns me the server date.

I tried this...

```
public static Date getCurrentDate() {

    final Date[] date = {null};
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    HttpRestClient.postData(ApiManager.USER_TEAM_LIST, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
        }

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String s = new String(responseBody);
            Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: " + s);
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                date[0] = format.parse(s);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: getTeam" );
            /*Toast.makeText(mContext
                    , "Server Error...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }
    });

   return date[0];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need to prevent a change of system time and date for my application

Comment: You mean you want to prevent the user from changing the system date and time?  I doubt that's possible.  In general the user is the boss of the system and apps do not have the authority to override user choices.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: yes, you are. I found one solution and I get network time using NTP

Comment: So your question is resolved?  If you want to take the time, it could be helpful to others to post an answer describing how you solved it (and accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found Solution

```
//if your thread not accept than add this
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


static InetAddress inetAddress = null;
static TimeInfo timeInfo = null;

String TIME_SERVER = "time.google.com";

NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();

inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
timeClient.open();
timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);

long returnTime = 0 ; 

if (timeInfo != null) {
      returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
}
```